# Heroku throws error (javascript heap out of memory)

Tags: reactjs, heroku

[image]

I have this error on Heroku and I don't seem to understand the error, it runs locally on my system.

Please help me out and if you need any source code let me know so I can provide it

Comment: "out of memory" seems fairly clear. Heroku's free dynos have fairly limited RAM available to them, far less than your local computer probably has.

Comment: You probably have an infinite loop in your code.

Comment: oooh.... I will take a look at it.  I am using redux-persist, do you think it will be an issue?

Comment: react is not complaining of an infinite loop, do you have any idea how I can debug it?

Comment: can it be an issue with firebase?